# How to query Model.KeyProperty == None in Datastore Plus(NDB)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Suppose a NDB(version 0.7 & 0.8) model with key which can be None:

```
class Test(model.Model):
    k = model.KeyProperty()
    value = model.IntegerProperty()

 count = Test.query(Test.k == None).count() # error
 #count = Test.query(Test.k != None).count() # error also
```

Only filtering key with None throws error.

```
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/_webapp25.py", line 701, in __call__
    handler.get(*groups)
File "/Users/reiot/Documents/Works/ndbtest/main.py", line 91, in get
    count = Test.query(Test.k == None).count() # error
File "/Users/reiot/Documents/Works/ndbtest/ndb/model.py", line 500, in __eq__
    return self._comparison('=', value)
File "/Users/reiot/Documents/Works/ndbtest/ndb/model.py", line 491, in _comparison
    return FilterNode(self._name, op, self._datastore_type(value))
File "/Users/reiot/Documents/Works/ndbtest/ndb/model.py", line 1138, in _datastore_type
    return datastore_types.Key(value.urlsafe())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'urlsafe'
```

How can I query KeyProperty with None?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in NDB. Can you file one on the issue tracker?

Comment: ok. i filed up at http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/issues/detail?id=77 :)